# firefox extension with js-ctypes on 32-bit and/or 64-bit firefox (version 25.0.1)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, 32bit-64bit, jsctypes

I am creating a firefox extension for linux firefox on 64-bit ubuntu.  The extension is a javascript program that calls functions in my shared library (libcog.so) written in C via the js-ctypes mechanism.

I got the basics of the extension working, but now that I need to call functions in the libcog.so shared library via the js-ctypes mechanism, several issues are unclear.

I can't make the firefox browser tell me whether it is a 32-bit or 64-bit mode application!

Later: I think I figured out this firefox browser is a 64-bit application as follows:

When I put a 32-bit libcog.so library in the /usr/lib32 directory but no libcog.so library in the /usr/lib directory the error console reports "libcog.so not found".

When I put a 64-bit libcog.so library in the /usr/lib directory but not libcog.so library in the /usr/lib32 directory, the error console does not report "libcog.so not found".

I assume this means the firefox browser is a 64-bit application, but I'm not 100% sure.

All the above raises various questions:

```
- Is javascript in a 64-bit browser running in 32-bit mode or 64-bit mode?
  - Does this question even make sense for interpreted languages like js?
  - Can javascript in 64-bit applications call 32-bit library functions?
- Should the js-ctypes mechanism even work in a 64-bit firefox browser?
  - NOTE: The library does little so far, but it does call and return.
  - If so, should function protocol always be specified default_abi?
  - If so, when javascript calls js-ctype library functions, is it:
    - calling 32-bit functions in 32-bit libraries in /usr/lib32?
    - calling 32-bit functions in 32-bit libraries in /usr/lib?
    - calling 64-bit functions in 64-bit libraries in /usr/lib32?
    - calling 64-bit functions in 64-bit libraries in /usr/lib?
    - or what?
```

Am I correct to assume:

#1: js-ctypes in a firefox extension in a 32-bit browser will always call functions in a 32-bit shared library in /usr/lib32 (or other 32-bit library directory)?

#2: js-ctypes in a firefox extension in a 64-bit browser will always call functions in a 64-bit shared library in /usr/lib (or other 64-bit library directory)?

With regular compiled-language binaries, many of the answers to these questions are rather obvious.  But an interpreter... I dunno... maybe they can fake or simulate almost anything?

Comment: In general, bitness mixing cannot be done within the same process. If javascript is started as separate process, it can be anything, regardless on parent process bitness. There is no fake which loads  32-bit .so within 64-bit process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`js-ctypes` really is just an abstraction on top of [`dlopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)/[`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`dlsym`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)/[`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

- Is javascript in a 64-bit browser running in 32-bit mode or 64-bit mode?

Right now, in Firefox, a 64-bit installation will only use 64-bit processes. In future versions, it is possible, but unlikely, that a 64-bit Firefox may create 32-bit child processes that therefore might embed a 32-bit js engine.

- Does this question even make sense for interpreted languages like js?

Well, in general no. Javascript is designed to abstract away the bitness and even processor architecture. But when it comes to js-ctypes, it might matter, as the goal of js-ctypes is to escape the abstraction and associated limits of the JS VM/engine.

- Should the js-ctypes mechanism even work in a 64-bit firefox browser?

js-ctypes works for 32-bit and 64-bit alike, and also for non x86 CPUs such as ARM. For example, the [OS.File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File) API, which comes with recent version of Firefox (and other mozilla-powered applications) does use js-ctypes internally, and is supported in x86 and ARM (well, *nix on ARM) alike.

However, while js-ctypes work, the binaries you interface with need to be platform specific, of course, and you need to correctly define their APIs (and ABI to some extend) in js-ctypes.

- If so, should function protocol always be specified default_abi?

This depends on the [ABI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/ctypes#ABI_constants) the library is actually using... For example, it is quite common for (commercial) library to use `winapi_abi`, because that is what windows uses for the system libraries. On *nix you'll mostly find `cdecl`/`default_abi` use, but a library author (e.g. you) is still free to use something else.

Either read the documentation for system and third party libraries, or when creating a library yourself, you should be already knowing what you're using.

- If so, when javascript calls js-ctype library functions, is it: calling 32-bit functions in 32-bit libraries in /usr/lib32?, etc.
- js-ctypes in a firefox extension in a 32-bit browser will always call functions in a 32-bit shared library in /usr/lib32 (or other 32-bit library directory)?
- js-ctypes in a firefox extension in a 64-bit browser will always call functions in a 64-bit shared library in /usr/lib (or other 64-bit library directory)?

This depends [on the system dynamic linker (and it's configuration)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes#Library_search_paths).
Most 32-bit operating systems won't even have a `/usr/lib32` directory. x86_64 might have a 32-bit userland, but where it is located might different from distribution to distribution.

`/usr/lib` usually contains libraries native to the OS platform and bitness. x86 distributions will contain libraries for 32-bit Intel, x86_64 (AMD64) distributions for 64-bit Intel, ARM distribitions... you get the drift.

It is quite common for code using js-ctypes to try a couple of libraries, often with (somewhat) hard-coded paths.

For example, `OS.File` will [attempt to load](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/osfile/modules/osfile_unix_allthreads.jsm#43) `libc` from a couple of hard-coded names, assuming the linker will figure out the library paths itself. Depending on the linker and other factors (32-bit Firefox on 64-bit OS), this might still fail, however.

In another example, in one of my own add-ons, I ship binaries for different platforms in the add-on package and just [try all of them](https://github.com/nmaier/mintrayr/blob/master/modules/trayservice.jsm#L43) until one loads. That way I can support different platforms, in this example right now Win32, Win64, most gcc/ELF x86 *nix and most gcc/ELF x86_64 (AMD64) *nix.
Of course, I had to make sure my library code is portable enough and does build correctly on different architectures and actually compile for all these targets.

I'd recommend you read up on shared object/dylib/DLL libraries and dynamic linking in general, because most parts of your question do not seem to be specific to js-ctypes, but more to library/linker/OSes in general.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answers.  Almost all my information comes from the MDN website and the book "Javascript for Web Developers, 2nd edition" (vastly better than my other 12 javascript/mozilla books combined).  I'm in the unfortunate position of needing to create this extension starting with zero knowledge of javascript, mozilla or browser extensions (but experienced C/system programmer).  Better js-ctypes documentation would help considerably.  I now have the basics of the extension working on my 64-bit firefox on 64-bit ubuntu, including calling functions in my 64-bit libcog.so library.

Comment: My confusion isn't with object/dylib/DLL libraries, only how javascript [with js-ctypes] interacts with them in all configurations (I've been writing and building conventional C/asm applications and libraries for years).  As a result, my brain is utterly habituated to thinking in terms of compiled (or assembled) code, and thus gets totally confused when trying to imagine what is conventional (or possible) for interpreted languages.  So much about javascript seems strange, unnatural, and confusing.  I could not make js-ctypes load/call my "coglib.so" with a path starting "chrome:". Why not?

Comment: js-ctypes simply does not support any protocol (not even the `file:` protocol), but only native paths, because that is what the underlying libffi/dynamic linker support. js-ctypes really is just an abstraction on top of `dlopen`/`LoadLibrary`and `dlsym`/`GetProcAddress`.

Comment: Man @honestann I'm opposite of you. I got js experience but no C. Were you able to pull of js-ctypes in linux? I would love to see your work.

Comment: @Blagoh: Yes, js-ctypes works fine on linux (in my firefox extension code).  I'm not sure what "pull of" means, but if you want to see some code, send email to my username at ymail dot com and we can communicate.  Are you good at javascript?

Comment: Thanks very much Ill email you very soon. Im decent at it :)